Issue While configuring outgoing and incoming mail server using outlook oauth Authentication
I am facing an Issue While configuring outgoing and incoming mail servers using Outlook OAuth Authentication.
Below is the error for the incoming mail server:-
Server replied with following exception:
 SELECT command error: BAD [b'User is authenticated but not connected.']

And Below is the error for the outgoing mail server:-
The server has closed the connection unexpectedly. Check configuration served on this port number.
 None

For authenticating the outgoing and incoming mail servers, I have configured Microsoft Azure with proper access user roles and API permissions.
While clicking to connect with Microsoft Outlook, it properly redirects to the odoo and shows "Outlook Token Valid" but clicking the test and confirm and test connection button shows these errors.
Is it because of using an alias mail id instead of the main mail id?
or any other reason for this mail issue.
